# NoClassDefFoundError com/google/inject/Module when running mvn clean install from cmd

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm learning about how to run Maven from cmd and I'm using Windows. I have a simple Eclipse project and if I run mvn clean or mvn install from Eclipse, it works perfectly, but if I run mvn clean or mvn clean install from cmd I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/Module
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container(MavenCli.java:635)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:281)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.inject.Module
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
        ... 11 more
```

If I run mvn -version I get this:

```
Maven home: C:\Program Files\Maven
Java version: 1.8.0_201, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

The environment variables for Maven are set in this way: `Maven_Home` `C:\Program Files\Maven\bin` and `Path` `C:\Program Files\Maven\bin`

The pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.dgs</groupId>
  <artifactId>hell-wor</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>[4.1,4.20]</version>
            <scope>test</scope> <!-- QUESTION : WHAT IS SCOPE? -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.ga</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <source>1.8</source> <!-- QUESTION : WHAT IS 1.8 HERE? -->
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

</project>
```

I see that I have the same problem with Intellij projects. If I create a project in Intellij and run mvn clean install, it works perfectly, if I run mvn clean install from cmd for the project I get the same error.

Any feedback will be apreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Can you post your Maven pom.xml ?

Comment: I just posted the pom.xml, it is very simple I just want to run mvn clean install from cmd

Comment: Does your Eclipse project have other `.classpath` entries that you set manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the error posted in this question, add the following dependency in maven pom.xml. This error comes up when Google Guice library is not available.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

You can find the dependency in the following link.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.inject/guice/4.2.2

Comment: This is the error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/Module
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container(MavenCli.java:635)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:281)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    ...

Comment: What is your maven version ?

Comment: The Maven version is 3.6.1

Comment: I have taken your code ie pom.xml and tried to run, it works perfectly fine in command line. I am using Maven 3.5.4 version and I am also using Java 1.8.

Comment: I also tried to run with the command mvn clean package or mvn clean install.

Comment: Thank you Sambit, I installed Maven 3.5.4 and now it's running perfeclty!